# How do I get my "estimatedCost" Double to update and print? NewToJava

Tags: java, eclipse

```
//Import scanner
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintCostCalculator{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Define variables
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    final double text = 5000; //Text dots per page
    final double image = 10000; //Image dots per page
    final double cText = 15000; //Compressed text dots per page
    final double statement = 7000; //Statement dots per page
    final double color = (5e-5); //Color ink cost per dots
    final double black = (1e-5); //Black ink cost per dots
    Double estimatedCost = 0.0;


    //Pages to print
    System.out.printf("--- Price Estimator Program ---%nEnter Number of Pages (digits only):  ");
    int pagestoPrint = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Print Type
    System.out.printf("%n---- Select a Print Type ----%nEnter T or t for Text%nEnter I or i for Image%nEnter C or c for Compressed Text%nEnter S or s for statement%n---------------------------%nEnter Print Type:  ");
    String pType = keyboard.next(); //pType is print type variable holder
    char PrintType = pType.charAt(0);

    //Print Color
    System.out.printf("%n--- Select a Print Color ---%nEnter 0 for Grayscale%nEnter 1 for Color%n-----------------------------%nEnter Print Color:  ");
    int printColor = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("-----------------------------%nIs there a sale (y/n): ");
    String sType = keyboard.next(); //sType is the sale type variable holder
    String lower =sType.toLowerCase();
    char saleType = sType.charAt(0);
    System.out.print(lower);

    //Calculation for color printing
        if (printColor == 1 && lower == "t") {
                 estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * text / color;
            } else { 
                if (printColor == 1 && lower == "i") {
                     estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * image / color;
                } else {
                    if  (printColor == 1 && lower == "c") {
                         estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * cText / color;
                    } else {
                        if (printColor == 1 && lower == "s") {
                             estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * statement / color;
                    //  } else {
                        //  System.out.println("oops");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    //Calculation for black printing
                    if (printColor == 0 && lower == "t") {
                                 estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * text / black;
                        } else { 
                            if (printColor == 0 && lower == "i") {
                                 estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * image / black;
                        } else {
                            if  (printColor == 0 && lower == "c") {
                                 estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * cText / black;
                            } else {
                                if (printColor == 0 && lower == "s") {
                                     estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * statement / black;
                            //  } else { 
                                //  System.out.println("oops2");
                                }
                            }
                        }

    //EstimatedCost variable change

    //Cost Estimate
    System.out.printf("%n--- Cost Estimate ---%nInk Usage Per Page: ");
    System.out.print( estimatedCost );
                        }
}
}
```

My Double estimatedCost will not update. Are my if else statements the reason for this? I have been looking and I cannot find what is wrong with this code. Where can I learn to better troubleshoot my code? Any tips?

Comment: Use equals for string comparison.

Answer (score 4):

> Are my if else statements the reason for this?

Yes your `if` statements are not well written because you are using `==` to compare strings. Strings should be compared using `equals` method.

For example this check

```
lower == "i"
```

should be replaced with

```
"i".equals(lower);
```

**Note:** reverse check against literal avoids NPE in case lower is null

Update your if conditions as mentioned above and try to run your program.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem. I have yet to read about the equals method. Can you recommend a Java book, I am not getting along with mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was still some mistakes, here's a correct version :

```
//Import scanner
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Define variables
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    final double text = 5000; //Text dots per page
    final double image = 10000; //Image dots per page
    final double cText = 15000; //Compressed text dots per page
    final double statement = 7000; //Statement dots per page
    final double color = (5e-5); //Color ink cost per dots
    final double black = (1e-5); //Black ink cost per dots
    Double estimatedCost = 0.0;


    //Pages to print
    System.out.printf("--- Price Estimator Program ---%nEnter Number of Pages (digits only):  ");
    int pagestoPrint = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Print Type
    System.out.printf("%n---- Select a Print Type ----%nEnter T or t for Text%nEnter I or i for Image%nEnter C or c for Compressed Text%nEnter S or s for statement%n---------------------------%nEnter Print Type:  ");
    String pType = keyboard.next(); //pType is print type variable holder
    pType = pType.toLowerCase();  //Added
    char PrintType = pType.charAt(0);

    //Print Color
    System.out.printf("%n--- Select a Print Color ---%nEnter 0 for Grayscale%nEnter 1 for Color%n-----------------------------%nEnter Print Color:  ");
    int printColor = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("-----------------------------%nIs there a sale (y/n): ");
    String sType = keyboard.next(); //sType is the sale type variable holder
    String lower =sType.toLowerCase();
    char saleType = sType.charAt(0);


    //Calculation for color printing
    if (printColor == 1){
        if  (PrintType == 't')
                estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * text / color;

        else if (PrintType == 'i')
                 estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * image / color;

        else if  (PrintType == 'c')
                 estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * cText / color;

        else if (PrintType == 's') 
                 estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * statement / color;
    }

    //Calculation for black printing
    else if (printColor == 0){

        if(PrintType == 't')
                 estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * text / black;
        else if (PrintType == 'i')
                 estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * image / black;
        else  if  (PrintType == 'c')
                 estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * cText / black;
        else if (PrintType == 's')
                     estimatedCost = pagestoPrint * statement / black;
    }

    //EstimatedCost variable change

    //Cost Estimate
    System.out.printf("%n--- Cost Estimate ---%nInk Usage Per Page: ");
    System.out.print( estimatedCost );
}
    }
```

You can't compare string with ==, you must use .equals() instead. With == you compare the adress stored in the reference.

The big mistake you made was comparing "lower" instead of "PrintType". lower contains the answer to "is there a sale" and what you wanted to compare was the printed type. So I changed that and added a toLowerCase() operation on printedType.